# Is there a way to convert blue ice back into packed ice?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just turned all my packed ice into blue ice (to save inventory space). I figured it was similar to crafting iron blocks from iron ingots (reversible). When I put the blue ice into the crafting bench, I was shocked to discover that I couldn't convert it back into packed ice.

Is there a way to reverse this conversion somehow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### There's no way to convert blue ice to packed ice in vanilla Minecraft.

The same goes for packed ice - can't be crafted into regular ice.

However, you can do this through datapacks, for example [Xisuma's Vanilla Tweaks](https://vanillatweaks.net/). One of the togglable features is uncrafting blue ice:

[image]